# Connection String to MySQL Database on LAN Setup

Tags: c#, mysql

With the service running on my machine(Setup on a LAN with no internet connection), I can connect with the following :

```
string sConnection = @"Server=localhost; Port=3306; Database=some_database; Uid=root; Pwd=genericpassword;";

MySqlConnection cnTest = new MySqlConnection(sConnection);

cnTest.Open();
```

How should I Modify my connection string to connect from another PC on the lan to my MYSQL server?
*side note : The IP of my local machine is setup to be 192.168.0.1.

Comment: checkout this, connection strings should be stored / maintained in something like a .Config file http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What goes after "Server=" is the address of the server.

So if your server is on 192.168.0.1 - it'll look like

```
string sConnection = @"Server=192.168.0.1; Port=3306; Database=some_database; Uid=root; Pwd=genericpassword;";
```

Just replace 'localhost' with the address you're given.

That said, it's generally considered to be good procedure to store connection strings in web.config / app.config - whenever you deploy it on some other environment, you won't want to rebuild it. [This link might help with that.](http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/)